# 256 color terminal library for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, xterm, ansi-escape, 256color

Is there a gem like '[Term::ANSIColor](http://flori.github.com/term-ansicolor/)' which works with 256 color terminals?  The perl script [256colors2.pl](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11apps/X11apps-14.1/xterm/xterm-235/vttests/256colors2.pl) works great in [my terminal](http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Rxvt), and I'd like to use some of these colors in my ruby scripts without manually inserting the ANSI codes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of the 256colors2.pl script to ruby, with some help from [this guide](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/). It defines a `print_color(text, foreground, background)` method that should be easily applicable to your projects. It prints the string in colour, and then resets the colour to the terminal default. Should be easy enough to skip the reset if you'd prefer that.

```
def rgb(red, green, blue)
  16 + (red * 36) + (green * 6) + blue
end

def gray(g)
  232 + g
end

def set_color(fg, bg)
  print "\x1b[38;5;#{fg}m" if fg
  print "\x1b[48;5;#{bg}m" if bg
end

def reset_color
  print "\x1b[0m"
end

def print_color(txt, fg, bg)
  set_color(fg, bg)
  print txt
  reset_color
end

# convenience method
def rgb_cube
  for green in 0..5 do
    for red in 0..5 do
      for blue in 0..5 do
        yield [red, green, blue]
      end 
      print " "
    end
    puts
  end
end

# rgb list on black bg
rgb_cube do |red, green, blue|
  print_color("%d%d%d  " % [red, green, blue], rgb(red, green, blue), nil)
end
puts

# rgb list on white bg
rgb_cube do |red, green, blue|
  print_color("%d%d%d  " % [red, green, blue], rgb(red, green, blue), 15)
end
puts

# system palette:
print "System colors:\n";
(0..7).each do |color|
  print_color("  ", nil, color)
end
puts

(8..15).each do |color|
  print_color("  ", nil, color)
end
puts
puts

# color cube
print "Color cube, 6x6x6:\n"
rgb_cube do |red, green, blue|
  print_color("  ", nil, rgb(red, green, blue))
end
puts

# grayscale ramp
print "Grayscale ramp:\n"
for g in (0..23) do 
  print_color("  ", nil, gray(g))
end

puts
puts
```

Answer (score 8):

This gem should handle what you need: [Rainbow](http://github.com/sickill/rainbow#readme)

Comment: It doesn't seem to show anything in colour on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that supports 256-colours -

> Paint manages terminal colors and effects for you. It combines the strengths of gems like term-ansicolor or rainbow into a simple to use and flexible colorizer.

[Paint](https://github.com/janlelis/paint)

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit with the earlier answer and got something that I found a little more fun to work with.

LIB

```
def gray(g); 232 + g; end 
def rgb(red, green, blue); 16 + (red * 36) + (green * 6) + blue; end 
def green; rgb(0,5,0); end 
def red; rgb(5,0,0); end 
def c( fg, bg = nil ); "#{fg ? "\x1b[38;5;#{fg}m" : ''}#{bg ? "\x1b[48;5;#{bg}m" : ''}" end 
def ec; "\x1b[0m"; end
```

EXAMPLE USAGE

```
BASE_DIR = File.expand_path( File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__), '..' ) )     
def status( sDaemon )
   b = File.exist?( File.join( BASE_DIR, 'pids', "#{sDaemon}.pid" ) ) 
   puts c( b ? green : red ) + sDaemon + ( b ? ' RUNNING' : ' STOPPED' ) + ec
end

%w{ backuper emailSpamChecker indexer log2email orderManager sitemapProducer }.each { |s| status s }
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a gem called Term::ANSIColor on Rubyforge... :)
No idea how good it is though.

http://rubyforge.org/projects/term-ansicolor/

Comment: That is the one he linked in his question.

Comment: To clarify that mentioned gem provides 8 color ANSI support.  I'm looking for the same sort of thing, with more colors.